# Should our faq questions be marked as CW?

Tags: discussion, tags, community-wiki

On the [main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and [stack overflow meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions are normally marked CW. Should we do the same thing on Politics, or should we leave the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions as is?

Note: the only change marking the questions as CW will make is that they will be editable by more users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think this is necessary because we are still on beta site rep requirements. As such, [a user needs only 1000 rep to edit posts](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

[Editing community wiki posts requires only 100 rep](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), which means that any new user who has received [the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648) on another site is afforded the privilege (unless they lost some reputation on this site).

From a cost-benefit perspective, I don't think allowing everyone to edit these posts will yield a lot of improvement. Most of the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts are fairly inactive so it's unlikely that users with less than 1000 rep will come along and improve these posts through editing. On the other hand, it's a possibility that the posts may be defaced or edited in a wrong way by someone with no prior participation Politics SE.